Question with a clear error message and an easy fix that was closed as "too localized", likely "not relevant to most of our audience". Reopen or Move?
Could this question How do I avoid error "Request to run job refused because the job is already running" if no job is shown as "running" when I start a chosen step? be reopened or moved to:

Server Fault SE (since it is about a server error while running an SQL Agent job)
or Super User SE (since it is just about how you work with SSMS)?

The question was closed:

Too localized - this could be because your code has a typo, basic error, or is not relevant to most of our audience. Consider revising your question so that it appeals to a broader audience. As it stands, the question is unlikely to help other users (regarding typo questions, see this meta question for background).

Yet, even if this error is indeed just coming up if you close that "running" box and forget about it and if its first step takes so much time, I found out about this only after some 10 or 20 minutes. I did not understand why it showed that something was running. Only then I got the idea of stopping the job from the menu, not from the "running" box.
It might be a tiny thing, but it cost some time and has a clear error message that is good to be found on the net.

There has been no interest in reopening the question. Reopen review was completed with a unanimous vote to keep it closed.
That doesn't mean it couldn't be reopened in future through the votes of people finding the question and answer useful to them.
Equally, the Q & A might eventually be deleted by users regarding it as useless. There haven't been any deletion votes so far.
As I understand the rules, the system won't automatically delete this Q & A for any of the normal reasons.
Migration is technically an option, but I don't feel strongly enough about it to do it myself. We generally only migrate things that are obviously in the wrong place and would obviously be in the right place at the destination. None of that seems to apply here. If you felt strongly that it belonged elsewhere, you could always delete it here and copy it there manually after all.
Otherwise, we are left with a Q & A that will continue to exist, but not allow new answers. Perhaps the passage of time will clarify what should happen to it as votes come in.
I think I would characterize the response to this Q & A as mild apathy. No one really seems to feel strongly enough to do anything final to it. I suppose your interest in it is the only thing keeping it going.
